# How to show dialog animation like this?

Tags: android, material-design

I want to show such animation on click on floating action button:
[image]

What is this animation is called? How to implement it in Android?

PS. This animation in youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdo95zNo408&feature=youtu.be&t=15

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/markushi/android-ui

try this link. It's have Reveal effect.